# VB Populating ComboBox with specific field from comma-delimited txt file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox

Need to populate NameComboBox from a comma-delimited txt file. Want user to be able to select just the name from NameComboBox dropdown and the rest of the textboxes to fill in.

Right now the entire record is populating the ComboBox.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class LookupForm

Private Sub LookupForm_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' Load the items into the NameComboBox list.
    Dim ResponseDialogResult As DialogResult
    Dim NameString As String

    Try
        ' Open the file.
        Dim ContactInfoStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("TextFile.txt")
        ' Read all the elements into the list.
        Do Until ContactInfoStreamReader.Peek = -1
            NameString = ContactInfoStreamReader.ReadLine()
            NameComboBox.Items.Add(NameString)
        Loop
        ' Close the file.
        ContactInfoStreamReader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' File missing.
        ResponseDialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Create a new file?", "File Not Found",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If ResponseDialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
            ' Exit the program.
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

****Update 11/2/15: 
The names are appearing in the NamesComboBox as they should but when one is selected the info doesn't show in the other text boxes. Also as soon as form loads its already putting info in the other textboxes (from the 1st record in the array) before any name is selected from NamesComboBox.

Heres my streamwrite form

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class ContactInfoForm

' Declare module-level variable.
Private ContactInfoStreamWriter As StreamWriter

Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    ' Save the users contact information to the end of the file.

    ' Make sure name field and at least 1 number field is not empty.
    If NameTextBox.Text <> "" And PhoneNumberTextBox.Text <> "" Or PagerNumberTextBox.Text <> "" Or
        CellPhoneNumberTextBox.Text <> "" Or VoiceMailNumberTextBox.Text <> "" Then

        If ContactInfoStreamWriter IsNot Nothing Then ' Check if the file is open
            Dim info As String = ""
            info = String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", _
            NameTextBox.Text, PhoneNumberTextBox.Text, PagerNumberTextBox.Text,
            CellPhoneNumberTextBox.Text, VoiceMailNumberTextBox.Text, EmailAddressTextBox.Text)
            ContactInfoStreamWriter.WriteLine(info)

            With NameTextBox
                .Clear()
                .Focus()
            End With
            PhoneNumberTextBox.Clear()
            PagerNumberTextBox.Clear()
            CellPhoneNumberTextBox.Clear()
            VoiceMailNumberTextBox.Clear()
            EmailAddressTextBox.Clear()
        Else        ' File is not open
            MessageBox.Show("You must open the file before you can save your contact information.", "File is Not Open",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            ' Display the File Open dialog box.
            OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e)
        End If

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your name and at least 1 number where you can be reached.", "Data Entry Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        NameTextBox.Focus()
    End If

End Sub
```

Heres my Streamread section on the form to lookup in combo box.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class LookupForm

Private Sub LookupForm_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' Load the items into the NameComboBox list.
    Dim ResponseDialogResult As DialogResult
    Dim LineString As String
    Dim FieldString As String()

    Try
        ' Open the file.
        Dim ContactInfoStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\Users\Cherokee\Documents\Cherokees Files\School Stuff\Visual Basic\Week 8 Data Files\pg465Ex11.5\pg465Ex11.5\pg465Ex11.5\bin\Debug\TextFile.txt")
        ' Read all the elements into the list.
        Do Until ContactInfoStreamReader.Peek = -1
            LineString = ContactInfoStreamReader.ReadLine()
            FieldString = LineString.Split(CChar(","))
            LineString = FieldString(0) 'Take First Field
            NameComboBox.Items.Add(LineString)

            'Set Textboxes based on position in line. 
            PhoneNumberTextBox.Text = FieldString(1)
            PagerNumberTextBox.Text = FieldString(2)
            CellPhoneNumberTextBox.Text = FieldString(3)
            VoiceMailNumberTextBox.Text = FieldString(4)
            EmailAddressTextBox.Text = FieldString(5)

        Loop

        ' Close the file.
        ContactInfoStreamReader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' File missing.
        ResponseDialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Create a new file?", "File Not Found",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If ResponseDialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
            ' Exit the program.
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Split the line read and take the column position you require as for example if first column is the name then your code becomes as below:

```
        ' Open the file.
        Dim ContactInfoStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("TextFile.txt")
        ' Read all the elements into the list.
        Do Until ContactInfoStreamReader.Peek = -1
            String lineRead = ContactInfoStreamReader.ReadLine()
            Dim fields as String() = lineRead.Split(",")
            NameString = fields(0) 'Take First Field
            NameComboBox.Items.Add(NameString)

            'Set Textboxes based on position in line. 
            'E.g. if Age is column 2 then
            AgeTextBox.Text = fields(1)
        Loop
        ' Close the file.
        ContactInfoStreamReader.Close()
```

Comment: Now I have the names showing in combobox but how do I get the textboxes to fill with the rest of the fields of the Name selected? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Same procedure applies for text boxes e.g txtAge.Text = fields(1)

Comment: I have this now but where do I put it? I tried right after the NameComboBox.Items.Add(Namestring) but it just loads the info for the 1st record in the text boxes.                                      `PhoneNumberTextBox.Text = FieldString(1)
                PagerNumberTextBox.Text = FieldString(2)
                CellPhoneNumberTextBox.Text = FieldString(3)
                VoiceMailNumberTextBox.Text = FieldString(4)
                EmailAddressTextBox.Text = FieldString(5)`

Comment: 6 fields per record (Name, Phone Number, Pager Number, Cell Phone Number, Voicemail Number, Email Address). Name is read in the ComboBox which is working. Now im trying to get the rest of the fields to appear in the lists boxes when user selects Name from comboBox.

Comment: Update question with this info and the structure of your form.